# Why this InputStreamReader throws an exception

Tags: java, eclipse, io

When I compile this code in eclipse ,it throws a NullPointerException,but the code in the book is written in this way.Here is this code.

```
 InputStream in = ClassLoader
            .getSystemResourceAsStream("javagames/filesandres/Test1.txt");
 try {
            InputStreamReader reader =new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because you probably don't have a "javagames/filesandres/Test1.txt" therefore, the `InputStream` will be null.

Comment: The code that throws an exception is `InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(in);`

Comment: That line is throwing an exception because `InputStream in` is null. You need to figure out why that is null.

Comment: I have  a `"javagames/filesandres/Test1.txt"`,and put it in the directory,but it will throw the same exception.